# running the same python script on multiple input files simultaneously in Slurm/Sbatch

Tags: parallel-processing, slurm

I'm trying to make a slurm file that runs a python script on tens/hundreds of input files. Each process is single-threaded and totally independent from each other and I want to speed things up by running them simultaneously.

Currently I'm doing

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1 --ntasks-per-node=1 --time=0:20:00
python3 xxx.py -i /path/input1
```

and I want to change it to something like

```
python3 xxx.py -i /path/*input
```

How should I change it so that all process could run in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1 --time=0:20:00
for i in {1..100}
do
    srun -n 1 python3 xxx.py -i /path/input$i &
done
wait
```

This will call your python script for the files ending with the name (1-100) i.e. `/path/input1` till `/path/input100`. Also, specify the `--ntasks-per-node` as the maximum allowed (eg: number of cpus).

The idea here is you can do scripting inside your sbatch job script.
The for loop will call the srun multiple times with different arguments (& ensures that srun will run in background without blocking). `wait` at the end will make the script wait till all the background jobs are finished. You can use variety of techniques to achieve the same objective.

Also you can use [job array](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html) to do the same more elegantly.

Comment: will the `srun` wait for the task to finish, or it will just launch 100 sruns without waiting for the individual jobs to finish?

Comment: No since we have put '&' after the 'srun' command (It will run in the background). To wait till all the background jobs are finished, we can use the 'wait' command. I have updated the answer. If you want srun to block/wait till the end of the tasks, just remove &. But then we cannot run multiple different tasks in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. Personally, I use [Hydra](https://hydra.cc/) to  parameterise anything in my python file. Then for parallel tasks I use the [Joblib](https://hydra.cc/docs/plugins/joblib_launcher/) plugin.

[Here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/blob/71ca75b2184a60161730eb857c592ff62eba7ece/plugins/hydra_joblib_launcher/example/config.yaml#L2) is a minimal. You can manage number of CPU and GPU, environment variables directly from the config file.