# SLURM: Run Same Parallel Script on Multiple Files

Tags: python, bash, gnu, slurm, gnu-parallel

What I'm trying to do is to run the same python script on thousands of input csv files. The python script is a single-process script that takes as input a single file and creates an output file with some summaries about the input. I saw the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76149684/running-the-same-python-script-on-multiple-input-files-simultaneously-in-slurm-s), and tried something similar but it did not work (see end).

My SLURM submission script looks like the below, and the python script is nested inside a bash for-loop. I'm using the loop because I have a large file with the names of the input csv files (one per line) and use it to dispatch the python script. The script is contained in a file, `submit_script.sh`, and it is submitted to the scheduler using sbatch: `sbatch submit_script.sh`.

I'm also using `sem` (GNU parallel) to parallelize the python script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=8
#SBATCH --ntasks-1024
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=128

OUTPUT_DIR='/path/to/output/dir'
INPUT_FILES='/some/path/to/list/of/inputs.txt'
INPUT_DIR='path/to/input/dir'
while IFS=read -r line

 FILE_NAME=${INPUT_DIR}/${line}.txt
 sem -j -1 --id ${FILE_NAME} python_script.py --input ${FILE_NAME} > ${OUTPUT_DIR}/${OUTPUT_DIR}.txt

done < <(tr -d '\r' < ${INPUT_FILES})

sem --wait
```

What I was expecting is that with the above SLURM submission, I would get 8 nodes, within which I would be able to create 1024 instances of the python script, and these would be sectioned in buckets of 128 per node? I'm still getting the hang of SLURM, and I apologize for any misunderstandings on my part.

What is happenning is that I do get multiple instances of the script going, but its only about 70, not the 1024 I was expecting.

I tried not using `sem` and replacing with `srun` (with no extra parameters), but that did not work — it created multiple copies of the script alright, but all ran with the same input file and the output went into a single file.

What I'm trying to do, is get the SLURM allocation with `N` nodes, and be able to spawn some number `M` multiple copies of the python script so that each can tackle a single file. The python script does not use threads and/or processes.

Many thanks in advance, and I really appreciate any help provided!

Comment: It would be useful if you can also specify how you schedule the script. Are you using `sbatch`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `sbatch`. Sorry for not mentioning it. I'll edit the post to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to be careful with your usage of `--ntasks-per-node`. The directives for `sbatch` can be a little bit confusing at first:

- `--nodes` -- this is the number of nodes that you are requesting for your job. Note: the number of CPUs per node **entirely depends on the cluster you are running on**. It could be 1 CPU per node; it could be 4.
- `--ntasks` -- this is the **total** number of tasks that you are requesting for your job.
- `--ntasks-per-node` -- if you specify `--ntasks`, this is the **maximum** number of tasks that can run on each node. Otherwise, it's the exact number. See the doc: https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html

If you know the number of CPUs per node (such as if you are using a homogeneous cluster), you should just use `--ntasks` and `--cpus-per-task` instead. That way you avoid oversubscribing to a node (which will throttle your performance).

Second, you want to use `srun`, not `sem`. See here: https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html

Third, your script itself is not quite right. When you run `sbatch`, you say: "please run the contents of this script later". SLURM runs it on the first allocated node.

When you use `srun`, you **immediately** run a job with the available SLURM resources at your disposal. Within an `sbatch`, that means you get to pick from the resources that were allocated with directives (`#SBATCH ...`). `sbatch` sets up some environment variables to make life easier.

When you want to partition stuff, you need to set that up all by yourself. SLURM won't intelligently "figure it out" -- you'll need to explicitly schedule.

I believe the final result needs to look something more like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=8
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=128

INPUT_DIR='path/to/input/dir'
OUTPUT_DIR='/path/to/output/dir'

# Read the file names into an array
INPUT_STEMS_FILE='/some/path/to/list/of/inputs.txt'
INPUT_STEMS=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
  INPUT_STEMS+=("$line")
done < <(tr -d '\r' < INPUT_STEMS_FILE)

for j in `seq 0 ${#INPUT_STEMS[@]}`; do
  # Iterate over the indices for each of the N files

  # Round-robin allocation to nodes (0, 1, ..., 8, 0, 1, ...)
  NODE_NUMBER=$(($j % $SLURM_NNODES))

  # Dynamically generate filename
  INPUT_FILE_NAME="$INPUT_DIR/$INPUT_STEMS[$(($i % $j))].txt"
  OUTPUT_FILE_NAME=$OUTPUT_DIR/$j.txt

  # Run a job on 1 task on 1 node, using the round-robin allocation.
  # The jobs run on different nodes, this way
  srun -N1 -n1 -r$NODE_NUMBER python_script.py --input $INPUT_FILE_NAME > $OUTPUT_FILE_NAME &
done

wait
```

I am not 100% sure about the following line:

```
srun -N1 -n1 -r$NODE_NUMBER python_script.py --input $INPUT_FILE_NAME > $OUTPUT_FILE_NAME
```

but I believe you need something like this. IIRC, `srun` with that syntax should continuously schedule tasks on 1 node, that node being identified by "index" `$NODE_NUMBER`.

This executes on each node using round-robin allocation. There are other ways of allocating the work.

---

As an aside, you might find job arrays useful for your task: https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html

They are a bit easier to use, but you create many more jobs. When you schedule a job array, you create M jobs instead of 1 job with M tasks.

Comment: An important note: `sbatch` just goes and grabs you the resources. It doesn't parallelize for you. **You** still have to parallelize. :)

Comment: Many, many thanks for your help!  Your answer and comments helped a lot! Thank you soo much!! :)